# Default column names while writing pandas df as csv

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I am trying to write a pandas df as csv file using to_csv function. After writing, I observed that pandas automatically creates default column names like below.

```
    _c0     _c1     _c2     _c3     _c4     _c5

0    A       B       C       D       E        F
1    a       b       c       d       e        f     
2    g       h       i       j       k        l
```

My actual column names are [A,B,C,D,E,F]. The following is my write function

```
df.to_csv(file_name,encoding='utf-8',header=True,index=False,columns=[A,B,C,D,E,F])
```

My expected format should be as follows

```
     A       B       C       D       E        F 
0    a       b       c       d       e        f 
1    g       h       i       j       k        l
```

I can get the expected format by executing the following lines after reading the created csv.

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

But, is there any way I can avoid the creation of these default column names before creating the csv ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How your dataframe looks like before you use `df.to_csv()` method?

Comment: You don't need to include `columns=...` unless you're writing a subset of columns.

Comment: @AnuragDabas Before using df.to_csv() dataframe looks like the expected format without default column names

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the "problem" is related to when you have imported the dataframe. You did not set up the header properly. I think  you cannot find the desired columns names in your df, don't you? How did you import this?

If you are reading it from a csv and use pd.read_csv make sure header=0

Comment: I can actually find the desired columns in iloc[0] and the actual column names are _c0,_c1,... 
I tried using pd.read_csv with header=False, still no luck

Comment: header=False means pandas will put default column names in your data frame that it is not what you would like. Header =0 will use the first line of you csv to find column names. how is your csv set up?@Sooraj

Comment: The problem was indeed while importing. I was importing this csv using pyspark and I had to explicitly mention header=True while reading the csv. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this fits for you:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{"A":"a", "B":"b", "C":"c", "D":"d", "E":"e", "F":"f"},
                    {"A":"g", "B":"h", "C":"i", "D":"j", "E":"k", "F":"l"}])
df.to_csv(file_path, index=True)
```

I think that your problem is that you are using the `columns` argument.

Comment: Hi Angelo. thank you for your answer. This is not feasible in my case as I am dynamically creating the dataframe and there are hundreds of rows in it.

Comment: @Sooraj That does not matter. The only line you need is the last one. I put the other lines to make a reproducible example, not for your code.

Comment: Understood. But as it turns out, my write was actually fine and the problem was while importing the output csv. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your custom header using `df.to_csv(header=...)`.
In case you don't need any, just put `header = False`.